# How to send values of variables stored in a function to another Python file?

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to create a program to play Tic-Tac-Toe. Now I need the "console.py" to send the coordinates of the mouse to the "core.py" when the mouse button is clicked. Here is the code:-

console.py

```
import turtle
import core
import graphics


def findPos(eve):
    x, y = canvas.winfo_pointerxy()
    print(x, y)
    return x, y

canvas = turtle.getcanvas()
canvas.bind('<Button-1>', findPos)
```

core.py

```
import numpy as np
import turtle
import console as tc

print(tc.x, tc.y)
```

Now,an error is thrown:

`AttributeError: module 'console' has no attribute 'x'`

How do I fix this?

Comment: It does not work like this. You do not send value to a file. There must be a function in `core.py` that has to be imported and called with those values as parameters.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this please?

Comment: You have to learn how to develop multi-file programs in Python. Your question is off topic on SO.

Comment: I tried importing the values of x and y( from `core.py` ), but it always  says `"console" doesnt have any attribute x`. Where am i going wrong here?

Comment: You need to post part of the code in `core.py` which is related to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function locally in `core.py`

```
import numpy as np
import turtle
import console as tc

x,y = tc.findPos(eve='eve')
print(x, y)
```

Is this what you are looking for?